# Using rxjs subjects vs. using a get method in a service class

Tags: angular, rxjs

I am curious about what the advantages of using an rxjs subject in a service class to push data to dependent components vs. having those components call a getMethod in the service class itself. In both instances we are getting the required data to the necessary components, so what's the point of using subjects instead of get methods - seems like more work than it should be just to get some data?

Comment: The difference with rxjs subject you get notified once value is changed in most cases you use observable to trigger a function one the value change... how would you know if a value changed in the service? you keep checking it all the time ? binding directly to service values isn't a good practice ...

Comment: Thanks @Hussein Akar

Answer (score 1):

I had the same question when I first started working with observables. The answer will become much clearer as you build out your app.

1. You can reuse the service and thus avoid repeating code.
2. You keep the code clean and separate, thereby making it easier to find, troubleshoot and test.
3. You can focus the component's typescript files to only handle what the component needs to.
4. To expand on Hussein Akar's answer, you will most likely have other components that are also making API calls and thus can subscribe to the changes they're making without needing to know who is making them.

Answer (score 0):

A `get` method is passive, you should call it every time when you want to get a fresh state, also it can be heavy and return an old value, that means the call was useless.

A `Subject` is active, once you're subscribed it will notify you once there's an update so you don't need to call it every time you want to check whether a new value is here and it makes your app reactive exactly when it should.